# rails でプロジェクト名の convention は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails では、もろもろの convention があります。

rails new から新規プロジェクトを立ち上げるとき、そのプロジェクト名について、従った方がよい規約はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rubyのgemを作成する場合の慣習のように強い慣習ではありませんが、
railsプロジェクトでは`-`でつなげるのをよく見かけます。

`config/application.rb`にプロジェクト名の定数が作られるため、
プロジェクト名のモデルを作れないことや、
`String`や`Rails`などすでに作られている定数をプロジェクト名にすることなど気をつければ何でも大丈夫だと思います。